# PyScripter - import argv error

Tags: python, pyscripter

I am using "Learn Python the Hard Way" and using PyScripter for writing and running my code.

On Exercise 13 I have to make the following code run:

```
from sys import argv


script, first, second, third = argv

print "The script is called:", script
print "Your first variable is:", first
print "Your second variable is:", second
print "Your third variable is:", third
```

When I run it, I get an error saying

```
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I have read other questions about the same topic and can't seem to find an answer that works.

I am also quite new to coding so explaining how to do it would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script will only work if you pass *exactly* three commandline arguments to it.  For example:

```
script.py 1 2 3
```

You cannot use any other number of commandline arguments or else a `ValueError` will be raised.

Perhaps you should make your script a little more robust by checking how many arguments you received and then assigning the names `first`, `second`, and `third` appropriately.

Below is a demonstration:

```
from sys import argv, exit

argc = len(argv)  # Get the number of commandline arguments

if argc == 4:
    # There were 3 commandline arguments
    script, first, second, third = argv
elif argc == 3:
    # There were only 2 commandline arguments
    script, first, second = argv
    third = '3rd'
elif argc == 2:
    # There was only 1 commandline argument
    script, first = argv
    second = '2nd'
    third = '3rd'
elif argc == 1:
    # There was no commandline arguments
    script = argv[0]
    first = '1st'
    second = '2nd'
    third = '3rd'
else:
    print "Too many commandline arguments"
    exit(1)

print "The script is called:", script
print "Your first variable is:", first
print "Your second variable is:", second
print "Your third variable is:", third
```

Of course, this is just an example.  You can do anything you want inside the if-statements (assign the names to something different, raise an exception, print a message, exit the script, etc.).  The important part here is the `argc = len(argv)` line and the if-statements which check how many arguments the script received.

Comment: Okay, i added what you put here, but the output should say,

"The script is called: (Wherever it is saved)
"Your first variable is: first"
"Your second variable is: 2nd"
"Your third variable is: 3rd"

but i get

The script is called: C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\Python\Exercises\module13.py
Your first variable is: None
Your second variable is: None
Your third variable is: None

Comment: Well, like I said, this is just an example.  You can do anything you want inside the if-statements.  But see my edit.  Instead on making the names `None`, it now assigns them to strings.